# How to set a determinate linear progress indicator

Tags: state, android-jetpack-compose, android-progressbar

I have put a linear progress indicator in my code in Jetpack Compose but
don't know how to set a value. It's determinate so the user can see the
detailed progress but it's not working

First setting state

```
 var ProgBarState by remember { mutableStateOf(0.1f) }
val onPGChange={pgState : Float -> ProgBarState = pgState}

val animatedProgress = animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = ProgBarState,
        animationSpec = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.ProgressAnimationSpec
    ).value
```

afterwards ...

```
  @Composable
fun CLProgressBar(ProgBarState : Float, onPGChange: (Float) -> Unit){
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)
            .background(Color(0xFF7DCEA0), )
             )
    ) {
        LinearProgressIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(20.dp),

           backgroundColor = Color(0xFF7DCEA0),
            color = Color(0xFF1C536F) ,


        )
    }
}
```

Don't know how to change the value of 'progress' any idea?

Setting ProgBarState=0.3f but nothing happend - progress bar stays indeterminate

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `LinearProgressIndicator` without the **`progress`** parameter, it is indeterminate .

You can use something like:

```
//Indeterminate
LinearProgressIndicator()

//Determinate
LinearProgressIndicator(progress = value)
```

In your case just use:

```
LinearProgressIndicator(progress = animatedProgress)
```

Comment: It's working - LinearProgressIndicator(progress = pgtext,will do the trick ... animatedProgress is not necessary

Comment: @VFarkas2023 You can use a fixed value, or you can use an animatedProgress to animate the progress to the target value.